# Auto suggest feature to search records

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know what is the exact name of this feature, but I need a feature where the user should be given a text box to search things. When they type in this text box, a matching list of values from database should be shown like a drop-down box.

The user can select one of the value and for will got submit.

I know this is already done on Internet anywhere, but what is this feature called?

Where can I find this feature to download and use for free?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : http://goo.gl/SYGlE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autocomplete from jQuery UI . SAYT opensource from Google.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

http://code.google.com/p/search-as-you-type/

Answer (score 3):

I found this code somewhere online, very very useful and very fast (tested for 30000 strings), have been using it ever since,

it uses `regex`

```
var rx = new RegExp('"([^"]*' + search + '[^"]*)"', 'gi');
var i = 0;
var num;
results = '';
while (result = rx.exec(string)) {
    results += "\n" + result[1];
    i += 1;
    if (i >= 10) break;
}
```

I've put up the entire code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLSdM/1/)

**NOTE:** My code(The HTML part) is extremely messy, was trying too many things at once, just correct it to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use the jQuery UI version [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).